# When 0$\leq a\leq$p - 1 how to show that $ord_p((ap^n!))$= a$(1+p+p^2+......+p^{n-1})$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

When 0$\leq a\leq$p - 1 show that $ord_p((ap^n)!)$= a$(1+p+p^2+......+p^{n-1})$.

What i know is let n≥1 and n=$n_0+...n_ℓp^ℓ$ be the p-adic expansion of n. Define $\alpha_p(n)=n_0+...+n_ℓ$. Then $ord_p(n!)=\frac{n−\alpha_p(n)}{p−1}$.

And also in the previous exercise $ord_p((p^n)!)$=$\frac{p^n - \alpha_p(p^n)}{p-1}$=$\frac{p^n - 1}{p-1}$=$1+p+p^2+...+p^{n-1}$ (since $p^n$=1×$p^n$ and so $\alpha_p(p^n)$=1)

But I have no idea how to do this exercise. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is not clear.  To what does the factorial symbol apply?  That is, do you mean $a\times (p^n!)$ or $(ap^n)!$ or something else?  Also, referencing "the previous exercise" suggests that you are just cutting and pasting without actually reading.

Comment: In any case, whatever you are asking should follow from [de Polignac's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)

Comment: I did the last exercise on my own but I have confusion in this given exercise. It is actually $(ap^n)$!  and sorry for that I will correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The $p$-adic expansion of $a p^n$ is ... $a p^n$.

Plug that into the two formulae you claim you know in your second paragraph and you're done. (I hope you know that $\dfrac{p^n -1}{p-1} = 1 + p + ... + p^{n-1}$.)